# How to take measurements for wavelength in an experimental wave tank?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, wavelength, experimental-technique, data-analysis

To anyone familiar with the experimental hydrodynamics field, how does one experimentally measure the wavelength of the waves generated in a plunger type wave tank or any wave tank for that matter? From what I've read so far, I've found it is calculated from a formula from [this](https://doi.org/10.1080/00221687409499732) paper by Wang. I have a surface understanding of his theory about plunger type wavemakers. I've constructed a plunger type wave tank but am stuck trying to take measurements for the a\WA vs kb curve from Wang's theory. If anyone could provide an explanation for taking the different measurements I would be grateful.

Comment: BTW, if this really is a low-budget do-it-in-my-garage type project the [home-experiment] tag would also be appropriate, but I didn't want to stick it on if you had a sophisticated machine.

Comment: Unable to access Wang's paper. If you have a sensitive enough pressure gauge available then you could make static pressure measurements beneath water level, and relate it to change in height above that gauge.

Answer (score 1):

No idea how the pros do it, but in a school science fair context I taped a ruler to both sides of the tank and simply photographed the action. When I got the developed prints back (yeah, I'm old...) I lined up a straight edge on the image of the two rulers for successive wave peaks.

It's tedious, but it works *and* you can convince even laypeople that what you have done is correct.

---

*Hint:* put a paper or white-board indicating which run is in progress in the frame, too. Otherwise correlating your photos with other data is essentially impossible.